# Unable to reproduce Chrome performance.now() precision errors

Tags: c++, google-chrome, floating-point, double, precision

When running performance.now() in a Chromium browser. You will face the following phenomenon represented in the example performance.now() outputs below.

```
147.5
150.09999990463257
151.19999980926514
152.09999990463257
156.59999990463257
164.89999985694885
168.89999985694885
172.89999985694885
176.89999985694885
180.29999995231628
185
188.89999985694885
192.59999990463257
196.39999985694885
201.09999990463257
209
212.5
217.09999990463257
220.79999995231628
```

I know the rounding errors occur due to floating point precision however I've been unable to reproduce the rounding errors in c++ or javascript. The rounding errors I can create look completely distinguishable/different from Chromium's.

I've tested the following c++ code but the rounding errors are different.

```
int main() {
    float sum = 100.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sum += 0.1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(17);

        std::cout << "Actual sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What specifically causes this phenomenon and how can we reproduce chromium performance.now() rounding precision error using code?

Comment: Um, what does `performance.now()` actually do?

Comment: *however I've been unable to reproduce the rounding errors in c++ or javascript* -- I wish you luck on this yeoman's work.  I would think there is no way to duplicate this on every single number, right down to the least significant digit.

Comment: At a guess it's slightly randomised to prevent timing attacks on other processes

Comment: Yep, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#security_requirements

Comment: *I've tested the following c++ code but the rounding errors are different.* -- And as soon as you change compiler or compiler options, you will get different results again.

Comment: If you are really interested in how Chromium's implementation of `performance.now()` works, you can start exploring the [source code here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/timing/performance.cc;drc=178cf6c1e3ff83d5596efa43aefdd4ef121e3067;l=1243) and trace the function calls. Also keep in mind that while the function returns a value in milliseconds, browsers actually measure performance in microseconds. So even if the observed behavior was due to just precision rounding errors, doing `+= 0.1` doesn't fully mimic the range of values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that when you change compilers/options the numbers will change. However the numbers returned by chromium performance.now() are similar no matter what device I use. They all look like 196.39999985694885 where it has a repeating 99999...

I'm trying to figure out how this rounding error happens so I can reproduce it in c++ code. I'm not trying to match the exact .00000000000001. However I'm trying to match the overall phenomenon/pattern. 

When I attempt to do so in c++ I do not get the repeating "999999" rounding error as I do in chrome.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, one of the reasons it is slightly randomized is to prevent fingerprinting. However by looking at the performance.now() of a browser you can easily tell if it's safari, chrome, etc based on the precision of the decimal. So I'm trying to understand how to reproduce the floating point precision errors that a browser would make. I'm not trying to replicate it to the exact decimal point but to replicate the pattern.

Comment: @PaulSanders The performance.now() method returns a high resolution timestamp in milliseconds. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: @BayanR does this somewhat mimic the behavior you expect? https://godbolt.org/z/f491vqv5r

Comment: Accumulating with `+=0.1` is a very bad idea in general (not only when tracking time) because you will get rounding errors in the same direction most of the time. More likely the time is kept internally as integer, converted (as integer) to 10000th of a second, and then multiplied by `0.1` to get a (double) value in milliseconds.

Comment: @DennisKats it doesn’t. the results are easily distinguishable which belongs to chrome.